# (How) is it possible to add additional annotations for 'Annotate method' in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations

IntelliJ has this feature to add external annotations to a method:

[image: Annotate method]

But it only offers these 3 annotations:

[image: available annotations]

(How) is it possible to add/configure additional annotations to be available here?

Like for example error-prone's `@CanIgnoreReturnValue`.

Comment: Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.